# How to check maximum allowed value for a double variable in R?

Tags: r

I am using `.Machine$double.xmax` to get the largest finite floating-point number.
The `if` statement checks whether the variables `n1` and `n2` are less than `.Machine$double.xmax`, however I am getting wrong output after performing `n1 %% 2` in Case 1.

My test code is below:

```
# Case 1
n1 <- as.double(9999999999999999)                   #16 digits
if(n1 < .Machine$double.xmax)
{
    a <- n1 %% 2
    print(a)
}
# Output: 0

# Case 2
n2 <- as.double(999999999999999)                    #15 digits
if(n2 < .Machine$double.xmax)
{
    t <- n2 %% 2
    print(t)
}
# Output: 1
```

How do I properly check a variable for maximum `double` value and prevent Case 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your test cases are *much* less than `.Machine$double.xmax`, which prints as `1.797693e+308`.  I think you want the largest whole number representable as `numeric`, which I believe is `with(.Machine, double.base^double.digits)`, i.e. `9.007199e+15` on my machine.  Here's a test that might convince you:

```r
largest <- with(.Machine, double.base^double.digits)
largest - 1 < largest
#> [1] TRUE
largest + 1 > largest
#> [1] FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

It's also true that your first test case is bigger than `largest`, and your second is smaller.